# Conflicting slf4j bindings in Intellij CE

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a spring boot project, imported in IntelliJ CE. On running it I get conflicting bindings for SLF4J.

One binding is from maven repository while another one is inside installation directory of Intellij CE.

There is no SLF4J explicitly configured in pom.

How can I exclude one of them?

Answer (score 0):

The error should contain the jars where it was found. It may come from one of your dependencies transitively. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103040/conflicts-with-logs-libraries-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings).

The jar could also be picked up from [_JAVA_TOOLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327620/difference-between-java-options-java-tool-options-and-java-opts) environment variable or [java.ext.dirs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039862/classpath-vs-java-ext-dirs) property.

Comment: I can see conflicting bindings in error message. But SLF4J is not configured in my project pom, meaning it is coming transitively. So I am not sure how to exclude one of the conflicting binding.